# Can an (Native/Web) app on mobile phone launch another (Native/Web) app in all the device?

Tags: mobile

is it possible to launch a app from another mobile app Also from native app? The requirement is for all the mobile devices.

Thanks in advance,

sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launching anything from a web application on a phone would be dependent on that phone's browser, and launching anything from a native application would depend on that phone's platform.

I doubt anyone here knows the internals of every mobile device, you'll have to specify which platform you are working on if you want any answers.

Comment: As am developing web application for Symbian, Android, Windows XP Netbook and iPhone. The requirement for this is to start another app from my app.